# How can I pass arguments in action different 3 level react components without redux and context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state-management, react-state

Suppose I have 3 components in a react App. **App** component, **Items** component and **Item** component.

My state is in the App component. Now I want to delete an item from the state via id. The onClick function is in Item component. The id from Item component goes throw Items component to App component.

I have tried it using .bind method and manage to 2 pass data Item to Items.

Comment: Please provide some codes you tried including App, Items, Item components.

Comment: Here's a phrase to keep in mind with React: *Data down, Actions up*

Comment: You don't need context for this. If `state` lives in `<App />` then define your `deleteItem(item)` in `<App />` which updates your state. Pass `deleteItem` down through to `<Item onClick={this.props.deleteItem}/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need redux for this. Context is nice but not necessary either. I prefer context tbh. But you can do it without them the following way:

```
// App.js
class App extends Component {
  state = { items: ...etc };

  handleItemClick = (id) => whatever

  render() {
    return <Items items={this.state.items} onItemClick={this.handleItemClick} />
  }
}

// Items.js
class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.items(item => <Item key={item.id} id={item.id} onClick={this.props.onItemClick} />);
  }
}

// Item.js
class Item extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return <whatever onClick={this.handleClick} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following thing - pass the onClick function as a prop from the 'App' component to the 'Item' component this way you have access to the state in the App component, and you pass an id parameter to it from the component that uses the function.

Generally speaking, I think that the Items component should hold the state and also the functionality not the App component nor the Item component which is just a UI component (stateless component). this way whenever you remove an item, the Items component will re-render itself because of the change in the state.

Comment: thanks, @Tomer. But, My Item is wrapping by Items component and get data from props from the same component. So it's maybe not possible. 

Secondly, I know that I should keep my state in Items. I even could use context api. But I'm learning how to send functions as props and get arguments in more then 2 level of component.